# Using google maps with Lightbox2

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

Does anyone know how to show google maps using lightbox2 by Lokesh Dhakar (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)  I can see lots of examples of showing images, but none on showing maps.  I was using lightbox, but it is problematic with later versions of jquery.

This is how to show an image

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-1">
    <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-1.jpg" alt="thumb-1" width="150" height="150"/>
</a>
```

I tried doing something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<a href="https://maps.google.co.za/maps?q=S29.103,+E30.104&hl=en&sll=29.103,-30.104&sspn=0.00824,0.016512&t=h&z=12" data-lightbox="map" >
    location
</a>
```

Comment: Lightbox2 is for images only.

Comment: Can you recommend anything for google maps - lightbox style.  The project is jquery/knockout/boostrap, so any library that works in that set of frameworks would be helpful

Comment: It's been too long that I used one so I can't recommend a specific product, but a query for `jquery lightbox iframe` turns up the most popular products - colorbox, fancybox, easybox and several others. They come with slightly differing feature sets, check out which one works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Straight answer

Lightbox2 does not support anything other than images.

### Alternative

Heres an [example of how to roll your own lightbox](http://jsbin.com/aBuSOC/4/) for Google Maps using some simple css and jQuery.

Basically the only real challenge is to resize the canvas on the first show of the overlay.

### Other lightbox alternatives

- [Easybox](https://code.google.com/p/easybox/)
- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
- [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: Thanks - looks good.  I did already try fancybox, but was getting cross-scripting errors.  Will keep trying and try the other two as well.